# Tableau: Using LOD to count distinct number of records based on a condition (10.2)

Tags: tableau-api

This question is similar to others but I'm having issues generating the correct output. I appreciate any assistance!

The goal is for a dimension,  count the number of distinct records if the string contains "List Email", otherwise count all records.

I've tried:

```
IF CONTAINS(ATTR([Subject]), "List Email:")
then ((COUNTD([Subject])))
Else COUNT([Subject])
END
```

(That works only if the dimension is in the view)

and

```
CASE CONTAINS(ATTR([Subject]), "List Email:")
WHEN TRUE   then ATTR({ FIXED  [Subject] : COUNTD([Subject])})
ELSE ATTR({ FIXED  [Subject] : COUNT([Subject])})
END
```

Workbook with Data: https://community.tableau.com/message/729431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the workbook and the "desired output" from the link, you are wanting to fix on `[User]` and `MONTH([Date])` (vs fixing on `[Subject]` as in the code tried in the question.

This is the field I created that gives you the desired output:

```
User Emails for Month:
{ FIXED [User], MONTH([Date]) : 
    COUNTD(IIF(CONTAINS([Subject],"List Email"),[Subject],NULL))
    +
    COUNT(IIF(NOT CONTAINS([Subject],"List Email"),[Subject],NULL))
}
```

For each User and Month, count distinct emails that contain List Email and add to that all emails that don't contain List Email.

Note that that matches the desired output. If instead the grand totals should be 3 for December and 16 for January (i.e., count distinct subject regardless of the user), then LOD calculation is not necessary:

```
# Emails:
COUNTD(IIF(CONTAINS([Subject],"List Email"),[Subject],NULL))
+
COUNT(IIF(NOT CONTAINS([Subject],"List Email"),[Subject],NULL))
```

Comment: Edited to include non-LOD calculation for if January emails should be 16 vs 17 (in other words if user should not be taken into account for the distinct count).